# Change order of div element

Tags: css, model, z-index

I have a on/off jquery switch on this page http://www.fospower.com/test that basically overlays the entire page in a dark color. However I need some help in trying to make the div below appear above the overlay. Any help is welcome.

I've tried changing z-index and overflow content but that doesnt seem to help any.

```
<div id="light">
    <div id="itoggle">
        <p style="text-align:center">Turn Off The Lights</p>
        <label class="itoggle iToff" for="lightswitch"><span></span></label>
        <input id="lightswitch" type="checkbox" class="iT_checkbox">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Make the new div a child of the the "dim-background-curtain" div, and it will appear in front of it.

Comment: Sorry j08691, i've updated to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the overlay via JS then just add the div after the overlay the same thing goes for if you are just using html then styling just add the div you want on top at the end and make it position absolute then it should appear on top of the overlay